# For the regular expression, (a* + b*) . (a.b)* , does the following automaton recognise the language it describes?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I constructed the automaton below using the assumption that the language described by the regular expression above only accepted the following strings:

Empty,
aabab,
babab,
aaaabab,
bbbabab  etc

Initially, I assumed that abab would not be accepted. (Not sure about this) Can someone please confirm if I have it right or if the automaton is missing something?

Initial automaton:
[image]

Fixed automaton: (Is this one correct?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression $(a^*+b^*)(ab)^*$ **does** include $abab$; in fact, it includes $(ab)^n$ for every $n\ge 0$. But your automaton is missing a great deal more than that. For instance, it doesn’t accept $aaa$ or $b$, both of which are in the language.

Your automaton accepts the empty word, every word of the form $a^nb(ab)^m$ with $n\ge 3$ and $m\ge 0$, and every word of the form $b^n(ab)^m$ with $n\ge 1$ and $m\ge 1$. A regular expression for that language is $\lambda+aaab(ab)^*+bb^*ab(ab)^*$.

Here’s a transition table for a DFA that works:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{state}&a&b\\ \hline
s_0&s_a&s_b\\
s_a&s_a&s_{ab}\\
s_b&s_{ba}&s_b\\
s_{ab}&s_{ba}&s_\infty\\
s_{ba}&s_\infty&s_{ab}\\
s_\infty&s_\infty&s_\infty
\end{array}$$

State $s_0$ is the initial state, and all states are acceptor states except $s_{ba}$ and $s_\infty$.

Comment: Ah, I just realised what I did...Thanks for clarifying about the abab. So i take it, the following will all be accepted then?: Empty, a,b,abab,aaa,bbb,aaabab,bbabab,aab,bab..and so on.

Comment: @zeqof: Yes, every one of those is in the language.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with the automaton I just fixed. Does that one correctly recognise the language described in the regular expression?

Comment: @zeqof: Yes, that looks as if it should work. In fact, if you combine the state at the top right and the state just to the left of the garbage state into a single state, you get my DFA.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your automato does not even accept $a$ (and also not $abab$ as you suspected). I guess all states apart from the far right ("in the middle of not the first $ab$") and the "error" state should be accepting.

Also, your automaton is not deterministic.

Comment: Yes thanks...I just realised where I went wrong. Fixing it now